# use variable in regular expression in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

May be it will be a very easy question some of expert but seems difficult to me. I want to use a `variable` in pattern of regular expression.

```
$("#srcbtn .btnPage").live("click",function(){
     var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

     $(".checkpoint").each(function () {
         if ($(this).find(".chpdetails .chkpname").text().search(new RegExp(/\b filter /i)) < 0) {
               $(this).hide();
         } else {
               $(this).show();
               count++;
         }
    });
});
```

but the filter variable doesn't work in `if` condition. the purpose of this code is to search a word which is start with `filter` variable's value i.e. A, B etc. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would consider changing the `live` emthod to `on` as it is deprecated, it will help in saving the hassle of updating such scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```
new RegExp("\\b" + filter, 'i')
```

See [the documentation on RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

If you have many checkpoints, you should probably build the regexp object before entering the loop instead of building it at each iteration :

```
 var r = new RegExp("\\b" + filter, 'i');
 $(".checkpoint").each(function () {
     if ($(this).find(".chpdetails .chkpname").text().search(r) < 0) {
           $(this).hide();
     } else {
           $(this).show();
           count++;
     }
});
```

Comment: this should work i know. but unfortunately this is not working. here is many checkpoints then how can i do this?

Comment: Did your code work before you tried to use a variable pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the constructor allows this for [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

```
$("#srcbtn .btnPage").live("click",function(){
     var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

     $(".checkpoint").each(function () {
         if ($(this).find(".chpdetails .chkpname").text().search(new RegExp("\\b" + filter, "i")) < 0) {
               $(this).hide();
         } else {
               $(this).show();
               count++;
         }
    });
});
```