# How do I create a regex for a string made up of a variable name followed by any character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

I need to verify "pathnames" of items stored in localStorage (pathname being a `string` like: `abc/localstorage/ualldocs/aalldocs` in order to filter whats in localstorage.

Right now I'm trying this:

```
priv.localpath = "abc/localstorage/ualldocs/aalldocs";

for (i in localStorage) {
  if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    s = new RegExp('\\/' + priv.localpath + '\\/.*$');
    if (s.test(i)) {
      value = localStorage.getItem(i);
      console.log( value );
    } else {
      console.log( "not found: "+i);
    }
  }
}
```

Which does not work = does not find anything.

**Question:**
How do I create a regex for a string made up of a variable name followed by any character?

Comment: Regex appears to work to me: http://jsfiddle.net/TYyzY/  Seems like something else is going on (what is the value of `i`?)

Comment: `i` will be the full "path" for example: `abc/localstorage/ualldocs/aalldocs/doc_1`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487156/use-variable-in-regular-expression-in-jquery/14487277#14487277

Comment: The way you're constructing the RegExp means you don't actually need to escape the `/`s (this isn't your issue though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the answer is still the same:

Using the constructor allows this for [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

```
    priv.localpath = "abc/localstorage/ualldocs/aalldocs";

for (i in localStorage) {
  if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    s = new RegExp(priv.localpath + '\\/*$', "i")
    if (s.test(i)) {
      value = localStorage.getItem(i);
      console.log( value );
    } else {
      console.log( "not found: "+i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: got it... no leading `//`... Thanks.

Comment: yup. my finished regex looks like this: `s = new RegExp(priv.localpath + '\\/.*$');` Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex in the loop is always the same, being:
    `new RegExp("\\/abc/localstorage/ualldocs/aalldocs\\/*$")`
which will translate into:
    `\/abc/localstorage/ualldocs/aalldocs\/*$`

I don't really understand:

1. why you regenerate the same regex in the loop;
2. what you're trying to achieve.

However, your answering your question:

```
var someString = "something"
var myRegex = new RegExp(someString + '.*'); // creates a regex for the string made up of a variable 'someString' followed by any character: '.*'
```

Comment: yah. would also be possible I guess. To answer your question, I have to create an JSON list of document titles stores in an application localStorage. There will be multiple buckets, separated by the string `localpath`. The actual files are `localpath/filename`. When the user queries allDocs, I need to only get the documents of a specific path, hence I'm filtering for the regex path plus "anything after". I need to create the regex inside the loop because i will differ with each iteration (e.g. path/doc_1, path/doc_2, other_path/doc3) and I only want the "path" files.

Comment: Got it :). Justins answer looks more precise than mine anyway.